# If a function on average is greater than another over the same interval, does this always imply that the integral of the bigger function is greater?

Tags: integration, average

I am trying to compare two integrals over the same continuous interval and would like to know if I could use the fact that one is on average greater than the other over a specified interval in order to at least prove that they aren’t equal.

Comment: Well, the integral of a function is simply the average times the length of the interval, so if the average is bigger, then the integral is bigger.

Comment: Thank you! Clever guy

Comment: Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: You should specify what exactly do you mean by "If a function on average is greater than another". If it is as @Crostul says, then that's that, but you may have had something different in mind, particularly with the wording "on average is greater", implying you do not mean the average of the function but something else entirely.

Comment: Yea, I meant the average value of one function being greater than the average value of another function , both over the same interval. Sorry about the title

Comment: Is the converse true?

Answer (score 0):

The average of $f(x)$ on $(a,b)$ is defined as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$, so if $\displaystyle \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx>\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx$, then multiplying by $b-a$ yields $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)\,dx>\int_a^bg(x)\,dx$